# .htaccess eg.php?id=3 to eg/id/3

Tags: apache, .htaccess

---

### Problem:

I know there are alot of examples like the title on the web, but non of them work properly for me. How do I get my .htaccess to rewrite AND redirect ALL pages like `/eg.php?id=3` to `/eg/id/3` and `/eg.php` to `/eg`

My current .htaccess

```
ErrorDocument 404 /404.php

<Files .htaccess>
order allow,deny
deny from all
</Files>

RewriteEngine On
```

---

### EDIT (WORKS)

```
RewriteEngine On
RewriteRule ^/?([^/]+)/id/([0-9]+)$ $1.php?id=$2 [L,QSA]

RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^www\.(.*)$ [NC]
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ http://%1%{REQUEST_URI} [R=301,QSA,NC,L]

RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteRule ^([^\.]+)$ $1.php [NC,L]

ErrorDocument 404 /404.php

<Files .htaccess>
order allow,deny
deny from all
</Files>
```

Fixes StyleSheet errors:

```
<head><base href="http://website.com/"></head>
```

---

Comment: Would you care to elaborate what exactly did not work for you with all those examples?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I'd say that should do what you ask for:

```
RewriteEngine on
RewriteRule ^/?eg/id/([0-9]+)$ eg.php?id=$1 [L,QSA]
RewriteRule ^/?eg/?$ eg.php [L,QSA]
```

Obviously the interpretation of `.htaccess` style files has to be enabled and the rewriting module has to be loaded for this to work.

This is a more general version as asked in the comments below:

```
RewriteEngine on
RewriteRule ^/?([^/]+)/id/([0-9]+)$ $1.php?id=$2 [L,QSA]
RewriteRule ^/?([^/]+)/?$ $1.php [L,QSA]
```

This further version should redirect requests still carrying a `.php` ending to their new versions:

```
RewriteEngine on

RewriteCond %{QUERY_STRING} (.*)(?:^|&)id=([^&]*)((?:&|$).*)
RewriteRule ^/?([^/]+)\.php$ $1/id/%2 [L,R=301,QSA]
RewriteRule ^/?([^/]+)\.php$ $1 [L,R=301,QSA]

RewriteRule ^/?([^/]+)/id/([0-9]+)$ $1.php?id=$2 [L,QSA]
RewriteRule ^/?([^/]+)/?$ $1.php [L,QSA]
```

---

And a general hint: you should always prefer to place such rules inside the http servers host configuration instead of using `.htaccess` style files. Those files are notoriously error prone, hard to debug and they really slow down the server. They are only provided as a last option for situations where you do not have control over the host configuration (read: really cheap hosting service providers) or if you have an application that relies on writing its own rewrite rules (which is an obvious security nightmare).

Comment: http://website.com/events/id/
Looks like the stylesheet file is gone. What could the problem be? And is it possible to have all pages that are like .php?id=1 be rewriten AND redirected to /id/1

Comment: I added a more generalized version of the rule set for that.

Comment: About the style sheet issue: this depends on how your links look like. Remember that I cannot look over your shoulder. You have to provide the details for all that. But actually that appears to be a separate issue, so you should post a separate question...

Comment: `RewriteRule ^/?([^/]+)/?$ $1.php [L,QSA]` causes Internal Server Error. (Fixed stylesheet error with `<head><base href="http://website.com/"></head>`) And is there also a way to auto redirect to this type of urls? Thanks.

Comment: I fail to see what should be wrong with that line. Could you please provide the corresponding error from your http servers error log file?

Comment: What do you mean by "auto redirect to this type of urls"?

Comment: I got the .php to work. (In the edit.) I mean if you go to `website.com/user.php` it redirects you to `website.com/user` or `website.com/user.php?id=1` to `website.com/user/id/1`

Comment: I added another version trying to force redirections of URLs that still carry the `.php` extension, but you will have to experiment a bit with that, I am afraid.